# How, within a CASE WHEN, to add multiple calculations?

Tags: sql, case-when

I am able, using two formulas, to get the answers I need, but need to add them together into one column.

Column A:

`CASE WHEN {netamountnotax} > 0 AND TO_CHAR({trandate},'YYYY') = TO_CHAR({today},'YYYY') THEN {quantity} * {item.custitem1} ELSE  0 END`

Column B:

`CASE WHEN {netamountnotax} > 0 AND TO_CHAR({trandate},'YYYY') = TO_CHAR({today},'YYYY') THEN {custcolpdunits} ELSE 0 END`

How do I add Column A and B into one column?  They have the same condition, just the "after the THEN" calculation is different.

What I've tried is variation on this and it returns `0`:

`CASE WHEN {netamountnotax} > 0 AND TO_CHAR({trandate},'YYYY') = TO_CHAR({today},'YYYY') THEN (({custcolpdunits}) + ({quantity} * {item.custitem1})) ELSE 0 END`

Thank you.

Comment: If you query Columns A and B _along with_ the total do you get values for A and B but 0 for the total?  The syntax looks right - something else must be wrong.

Comment: Yes, this is the frustrating part.  Column A would have 8 and Column B would have 30.  Trying to get 38 to appear in the total column and I am getting 0.

Comment: "would have" - but have you put the three expression in the same query and verified that A and B have values but the total is 0?  Can you post the entire query instead of just those expressions?

Comment: I have the three expression in the saved search - Column C is the total.  A and B have values but C is 0.  So, A is correct with 8, B is correct with 30 but C is not correct with 0 and should show 38.  Thank you.

Comment: And all three columns (`custcolpdunits`, `quantity`, and `item.custitem1`) are numeric?

Comment: Can you post the complete query?

Comment: Thank you for asking.  Yes, I believe all are numeric.

Comment: Sorry - not sure how to post the entire query.  Does not seem to let me copy and paste the image.

Comment: Can you post the _text_ of the query?